# Share Dialog not Functioning

Tags: android, facebook-graph-api, share

I have the following code for my Share Dialog inside the fragment:

**TabFour.java**

```
public class TabFour extends Fragment {
private UiLifecycleHelper uiHelper;
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_tab_four, container, false);

    return rootView;
}

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    uiHelper = new UiLifecycleHelper(getActivity(), callback);
    uiHelper.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    OpenGraphAction action = GraphObject.Factory.create(OpenGraphAction.class);
    action.setProperty("book", "https://example.com/book/Snow-Crash.html");

    @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
    FacebookDialog shareDialog = new FacebookDialog.OpenGraphActionDialogBuilder(getActivity(), action, "books.reads", "book")
            .build();
    uiHelper.trackPendingDialogCall(shareDialog.present());
}


@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    uiHelper.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data, new FacebookDialog.Callback() {
        @Override
        public void onError(FacebookDialog.PendingCall pendingCall, Exception error, Bundle data) {
            Log.e("Activity", String.format("Error: %s", error.toString()));
        }

        @Override
        public void onComplete(FacebookDialog.PendingCall pendingCall, Bundle data) {
            Log.i("Activity", "Success!");
        }
    });
}



@Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    uiHelper.onResume();
}

@Override
public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
    uiHelper.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
}

@Override
public void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    uiHelper.onPause();
}

@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    uiHelper.onDestroy();
}
private Session.StatusCallback callback = new Session.StatusCallback() {


    @Override
    public void call(Session session, SessionState state,
            Exception exception) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }
};
```

}

The Facebok Share loads on the emulator, however it does not on a phone. Also when the Share Dialog loads on the emulator, you can't share it because the share button on the upper left is disabled(visible but can't be clicked). Also, the emulator displays a toast message "Share Preview could not be fetched." Please help!

I hope someone can explain this to me. Thanks!

Comment: do u have facebook app on your emulator? and also check the version of facebook app. do u see any adb error log?

Answer (score 0):

From https://developers.facebook.com/docs/android/share

The facebook share dialog only works if facebook app is installed. So the suggested method is to first check whether the Share Dialog can be presented and if presentable, present it with your content or use a Web Dialog to present the share screen. i.e

```
if (FacebookDialog.canPresentShareDialog(getApplicationContext(), 
                                             FacebookDialog.ShareDialogFeature.SHARE_DIALOG)) 
{
        // Publish the post using the Share Dialog
        FacebookDialog shareDialog = new FacebookDialog.ShareDialogBuilder(this)
                .setLink("https://developers.facebook.com/android")
                .build();
        uiHelper.trackPendingDialogCall(shareDialog.present());

} 
else 
{
      // Fallback. For example, publish the post using the Feed Dialog
}
```

And here is the else option's example

```
private void publishFeedDialog() {
    Bundle params = new Bundle();
    params.putString("name", "Facebook SDK for Android");
    params.putString("caption", "Build great social apps and get more installs.");
    params.putString("description", "The Facebook SDK for Android makes it easier and faster to develop Facebook integrated Android apps.");
    params.putString("link", "https://developers.facebook.com/android");
    params.putString("picture", "https://raw.github.com/fbsamples/ios-3.x-howtos/master/Images/iossdk_logo.png");

    WebDialog feedDialog = (
        new WebDialog.FeedDialogBuilder(getActivity(),
            Session.getActiveSession(),
            params))
        .setOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener() {

            @Override
            public void onComplete(Bundle values,
                FacebookException error) {
                if (error == null) {
                    // When the story is posted, echo the success
                    // and the post Id.
                    final String postId = values.getString("post_id");
                    if (postId != null) {
                        Toast.makeText(getActivity(),
                            "Posted story, id: "+postId,
                            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    } else {
                        // User clicked the Cancel button
                        Toast.makeText(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), 
                            "Publish cancelled", 
                            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                } else if (error instanceof FacebookOperationCanceledException) {
                    // User clicked the "x" button
                    Toast.makeText(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), 
                        "Publish cancelled", 
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                } else {
                    // Generic, ex: network error
                    Toast.makeText(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), 
                        "Error posting story", 
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }

        })
        .build();
    feedDialog.show();
}
```

And don't always rely on the emulator for checking things out. After all its just an "emulator" . You can easily preview your app on the real device. So if things ain't running as it is supposed to, on the emulator, verify it on the real device. (Of course, I agree, emulator is good when u dont have multiple devices, screen sizes etc.)

PS : You also need to have your Key Hashes set properly in the app settings page on the fb developers website.